# top, margin-top and padding-top --- How do they differ?

Tags: css

The question is: **How do they differ?**

My understanding is this:

`margin-top` is similar to margin that we are used to in `MS Word`. This is more like the white space around the page. When used, it determines how far from the top or wherever the content will be from their containing element. If the content is in the `div` tag then the position will be calculated relative to `div` but if there is no containing element then it will be calculated relative to the browser. it does push down the other content.

`top` is used to push the content down and is used as a *tweak* for `position` property. It will push the content down without harming the other content. In other words, it provides fine grained control.

`padding-top` will also push content down while adding space to the top.

**Am I getting this correctly?**

Comment: Have you tried reading any of the many sources of CSS info on the web about this?

Comment: Seems like you're already answering your own question. You should provide some examples that show times where the output is not what you expected.

Comment: Sometimes a picture can help explain it too: http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-background/box

Answer (score 1):

Based on what I search:

Margin is on the outside of block elements, while padding is on the inside, and top to have element be independent (position wise).

use margin(margin-top) to separate the block from things outside it, padding(padding-top) to move the contents away from the edges of the block, and finally top if need to have element be roamed by position call.

Answer (score 1):

### Margins

Margins suffer from [margin collapse](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/box.html#collapsing-margins) - if the *vertical* margins are deemed to be adjacent (e.g. no border separating them), then the separation between the two elements will not be the sum of their respective, adjacent margins, but the larger of the two margins. Meanwhile, *horizontal* margins never collapse.

Margins lie outside the box of an element.

### Paddings

Top paddings work as they are expected to, and does not suffer from collapse. However, top paddings, when defined in percentages, will be a percentage of the element's width and not height.

Paddings lie within the box of an element. If you define the dimensions of an element to be 500*500px and set the padding to 20px, then the actual dimensions of the said element will be 540*540px (500 + 20 + 20). This can be circumvented by using `box-sizing: border-box`, which tells the browser to render the element as defined by the width and height attributes, inclusive of all borders AND paddings.

### Top

Top on the other hand, will displace the said element from:

- it's parent container, if the parent container is relatively positioned,
- the viewport, if the said element has a fixed position,
- the document, if the said element has an absolute position and whose parent is not relatively positioned.

More importantly, top position offset percentages are based on the parent's height, not width (unlike padding).

Comment: Margins *benefit* from margin collapse. Just write paragraphs of text without this mechanism...

Comment: Outside/inside the box: OP should add a border to see where is the *edge* of this box. Or a background-color to better see it.

Comment: `top` for absolutely positioned elements refers to their closest parent that is positioned and if there's none than it's relative to *the page* (`<html>`)