# Margin-top or Padding-top or top?

Tags: css

I confuse `padding-top`, `margin-top` and `top`. 
My problem is that I want to create a space of `15px`.

With a `margin-top: 15px` it's ok but I think it's an error?

```
.subtitles{
  font-size:13px;
  font-family: "Open Sans","Helvetica Neue",Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif;
  text-transform:  uppercase;
  text-align: center;
  margin-top: 15px;
}
```

Here my code below:

```css
    header{
  background-color: #535353;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100px;
  top:  0;
  left: 0;
  display: block;
  position:  absolute;
}

.subtitles{
  font-size:13px;
  font-family: "Open Sans","Helvetica Neue",Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif;
  text-transform:  uppercase;
  text-align: center;
  margin-top: 15px;
}

.subtiles-left{
  display: inline-block;
  padding-right: 10px; 
}

.subtiles-right{
  display: inline-block;
  padding-right:  18px;
  float: right;
}
```

```html
    <header>
      <div class="subtitles">
        <div class="subtiles-left">Portofolio</div>
        <div class="subtiles-left">Languages</div>
        <div class="subtiles-right">Support</div>
        <div class="subtiles-right">Login</div>
      </div>
    </header>
```

Comment: What are you expecting to occur that is not happening?

Comment: What makes you think it's an error? I mean, it's a bit odd to use `15px` to make a space of `10px`, but whatever it takes...

Comment: @ Jeremy Harris: is it my code is correct?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [top, margin-top and padding-top --- How do they differ?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15278595/top-margin-top-and-padding-top-how-do-they-differ)

Comment: Your question is unclear. It would be subjective of me to say your code is correct without understanding what you want to accomplish. Why do you think using margin-top is an error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is not an error. You can use either margin or padding depending on what you want to achieve.

I think of margin as affecting the space after the border and padding affects space within the border.

Margin can be used to place the parent element since it can have negative values while padding is more of placing the element within the border and cannot have negative values.

Top is usually used to place the element in relation to the parent e.g. having style position of relative or absolute. It can also have negative values.

[margin-top according to MDN web docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/margin-top)

[padding-top according to MDN web docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/padding-top)

[top according to MDN web docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/top)